# Video Gallery: Click on text, have video appear

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

This would seem to be an easy task with HTML, CSS, and/or Javascript, but I cannot frind a solution, either by Googling it, or consulting the database on Stack Overflow.

What I want, and have seen, is to have several rows of text naming videos on the left.  When you click on one of the video names, the video will appear to the right or above.  Every time you click on a video name, the video displays in the same box to the right. So, it's kind of like switching channels and the text anchors are your remote.

An example would be MSNBC, however I think this is way over my pay grade:

http://www.msnbc.com/msnbc/watch/clinton-on-email-scandal-i-want-it-resolved-612366403989)

Another example that I found by searching Stack Overflow, but uses images instead of video is this one:

http://imagethrow.com/design-studio-all-throws.html

My question is: Can a simple video player, that responds by clicking on text anchors, be created, or is this simply too complex (at least for my level of understanding, i.e. I don't do php).  Thanks for any help.

Barry Glick

Comment: Welcome to SO. What method are you using to display the video? Are they youtube embeds or HTML <video> tag? Sharing your code and what you have tried will help us a lot, ideally a jsFiddle demo

Comment: YouTube Embeds.  Window.open works good, but I don't want my users, who are not very tech savvy, to click on the main page, and throw the video window behind the main page.  Is there any way to keep the opened window on top?  Or another way entirely?

Comment: would there be a default video playing?

Comment: No.  Blank page, except for Anchor text or buttons naming the videos.  Here's what I've tried with my limited knowledge: [link] (http://ollapodridawhatuneeda.com/video_library.html) but if I click any where on the parent page, the video drops behind the parent page

Answer (score 0):

Ok for this to work, you need to create a container for the video and then have a set of links change the video source when clicked on them through JavaScript/jQuery.

As you are going with YouTube for the videos, we will be using the youtube embed code (iframe)

**Demo - [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/azizn/99a7ftzh/)**

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {

  // load video function on link click
  $( "#video-list" ).on( "click", "a", function(e) {
    // prevent default anchor behaviour
    e.preventDefault();
    // get the video URL from link
    var videoID = $(this).attr('data-video');
    // load the video into the iframe
    $('#videoContainer iframe').attr("src", videoID);
  });
    
});
```

```css
#videoContainer {
  height: 350px;
  width:600px;
}

#videoContainer iframe {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- video container -->
<div id="videoContainer">
  <!-- youtube's iframe embed code - you can set a default video here -->
  <iframe id="youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<!-- videos list -->
<ul id="video-list">
  <li><a href="#" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/IWegh6TRx6c">Lord Trolldemort</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9_1TDrwaMOc">Fabulous Secret Powers</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-video="https://www.youtube.com/embed/1dWjKkF0Zi4">Consequences</a></li>
</ul>
```

The code is pretty commented but if you have any questions let me know!

Comment: Firstly, I can't thank you enough for your help.  I am not so experienced, so I am still having a small problem.  I don't know if I've done it as you told me to.  Here's the link: [link] http://ollapodridawhatuneeda.com/Video_viewer.html for the page.  I am not sure if I placed all the script tags and javascript correctly.   The links don't work, although everything works fine on jsfiddle.  So, if you can be bothered to comment on where I went wrong, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Is the # sign in the link a dummy, that I need to delete?  Because when I hover over the links, I get video_viewer.html#.  I'm sorry if my level is to low for you to bother with.  I thank you for your assistance.

Comment: I think you can remove the href attribute altogether. Anyway, your link is working fine for me - what browser are you using?

Comment: You're right!  My Internet wasn't working (as is common here in Vermont).  It works great!  Thanks so much for your help.  This is just what I wanted.

Comment: glad I could help! please go ahead and accept my answer by clicking on the check mark under the votes count. have a nice day!